# Sobre middleware after y before

Tags: laravel, middleware, after

Estoy leyendo la documentación de Laravel sobre Middlewares, en concreto la parte que habla de [after y before](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#defining-middleware). No entiendo el concepto. Parece que el Middleware before se ejecuta cuando llega la petición, y de él depende que la petición siga o no hasta el controlador. Hasta aquí, está claro.

Sin embargo, lo del after no lo veo claro. Creo entender que primero la petición pasa al controlador y luego se ejecuta el middleware. Sin embargo, lo he probado y no parece funcionar así. He usado un Middleware que filtra en base al valor de un dato, a modo de prueba:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    $id = $request->route('id');

    if ($id < 30) {
        dd("El id no es válido");
    }

    return $response;
}
```

El caso es que con este código, sea cual sea el valor de `id` se pasa directamente al controlador, y el Middleware no hace nada, ni muestra nada, ni antes ni después.

Lo que pido es que alguien me aclare el concepto y me muestre algún ejemplo que lo ilustre, que yo pueda reproducir y ejecutar, para entender lo de after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por ejemplo, tienes un middleware `BeforeMiddleware` que controla si el parámetro `{id}` de la ruta es menor a 30, y si es así, redirige a la vista `welcome` con un mensaje de sesión flash que indica que fué redirigido por este middleware. De lo contrario, continúa con la ejecución de la aplicación:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class BeforeMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $id = $request->route('id');
        if ($id < 30) {
            session()->flash('redirected_by', "redirected_by BeforeMiddleware");
            return redirect()->route('welcome');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Además, tienes un middleware `AfterMiddleware` que controla si el parámetro `{id}` de la ruta es menor a 40, y si es así, redirige a la vista `welcome` con un mensaje de sesión flash que indica que fué redirigido por este otro middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AfterMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $id = $request->route('id');
        if ($id < 40) {
            session()->flash('redirected_by', "redirected_by AfterMiddleware");
            return redirect()->route('welcome');
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Tienes estas dos rutas, que retornan cada una vista diferente. A la ruta que espera el parámetro `{id}`, le aplicas ambos middlewares:

**web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Middleware\BeforeMiddleware;
use App\Http\Middleware\AfterMiddleware;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome');

Route::get('/{id}', function ($id) {
    return view('id_valido', ['id' => $id]);
})
->where('id', '[0-9]+')
->middleware([
    BeforeMiddleware::class,
    AfterMiddleware::class,
]);
```

Las vistas son bien simples. Solo que en la vista `welcome`, se muestra el valor de sesión que se setea en los middlewares:

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Welcome View
        </h1>
        <p>{{session()->get('redirected_by')}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**id_valido.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Id Valido View
        </h1>
        <h3>
            Id: {{$id}}
        </h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Con eso ya puedes probarlo.

Si ingresas, por ejemplo, a [localhost:8000/21](http://localhost:8000/21), no pasará el `BeforeMiddleware` (21 es menor que 30), por lo que serás redirigida a la ruta `welcome`, que en la vista que devuelve te mostrará el siguente mensaje:

> Welcome View
> redirected_by BeforeMiddleware

Si ingresas a [localhost:8000/31](http://localhost:8000/31), sí pasará el `BeforeMiddleware` (31 no es menor que 30), pero no pasará el `AfterMiddleware` (31 es menor que 40), por lo que serás redirigida a la ruta `welcome`, que en la vista te mostrará el siguente mensaje:

> Welcome View
> redirected_by AfterMiddleware

Finalmente, si ingresas a [localhost:8000/41](http://localhost:8000/41), sí pasará el `BeforeMiddleware` (41 no es menor que 30), y también pasará el `AfterMiddleware` (41 no es menor que 40), por lo que retornará la vista `id_valido.blade.php`:

> Id Valido View
> Id: 41